# Which test (or regression) to run with a categorical DV and a mix of continuous and categorical covariates?

Tags: regression, ordinal-data

I am looking into which test I should run for a question regarding the likelihood that something would happen [to the participant]. They answered based on likelihood (not likely at all, somewhat not likely, neither likely nor unlikely, somewhat likely, very likely). Thus, my DV has 5 levels. I have 5 IVs: 1 grouping factor (3 subgroups) and a mix of continuous (ie. age) and categorical (ie. religion) covariates.

I was looking into the various types of analyses but do not see which would be most appropriate.
For the purpose of the covariates, I initially looked into an ANCOVA but read the covariates need to be continuous (which I have a few categorical covariates as well). I had then looked into a regression, in which the two options seem to be either an ordinal logistic regression or a multinomial regression. Initially, it seems the multinomial regression would make the most sense as I do not assign some arbitrary range between likely and not likely, rather whichever response the participant answers is simply their opinion and not right/wrong. However, I read for a multinomial regression you must have a baseline group to compare, in which I have three groups but one is not designated as a control so to speak.

Does anyone have any advice as to these options and what is statistically appropriate?

Comment: Ordinal regression of some kind wild Abe appropriate here, but that’s a regression model, not a test. What do you want to test?

Comment: @Dave perhaps I used the word 'test' too loosely. I am looking for a regression model, as I understand that they should mathematically resemble an ANCOVA? Essentially, I am looking at whether the DV differs between the groups, and whether the covariates are predictive of the outcome.

Comment: Okay, then you’ll want to run some kind of ordinal regression and then start getting into testing the parameters or groups of parameters, similar to how you would for a linear regression.

Comment: @Dave However, an ordinal regression would assume some distance between values, such as ranking one option as higher than another, correct?

Comment: Yes, and that’s exactly what you have in your response variable.